# QUOTE with multiple arguments

Tags: lisp

I'm analyzing LISP, I'm no expert, but something is bothering me:

Some primitives as `list` accepts more than one parameter. e.g.:

```
(list 1 2 3)
=> (1 2 3)
```

On the other hand `quote` seems to accept just one parameter. e.g:

```
(quote (1 2 3))
=> (1 2 3)
(quote x)
=> 'x
(quote 1 2 3)
=> 1  ???
```

Is there a reason why `(quote 1 2 3)` i.e. quote with multiple params, just ignores the other arguments?

what will happen if `(quote 1 2 3)` evaluates to `(1 2 3)`, i.e. an special case when more than one argument is supplied?

I do understand that this special case is superfluous, but my question to LISP hackers is:

adding such special case to `quote` will break everything? will it break the REPL? will it break macros?

*Note: tested on http://repl.it/ and http://clojurescript.net/*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that Lisp is not a single language, but a large family of somewhat similar languages. You seem to have tried out Scheme (repl.it runs BiwaScheme) and ClojureScript.

The [Scheme spec](http://www.r6rs.org/) only defines one argument for `quote`, so BiwaScheme seems to be wrong in that respect. `(quote 1 2 3)` should be an error in Scheme. For example, [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/), another dialect of Scheme, does not accept them:

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v5.3.6.
> (quote 1)
1
> (quote 1 2 3)
stdin::10: quote: wrong number of parts
  in: (quote 1 2 3)
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

BiwaScheme is written in JavaScript, and JavaScript simply ignores extra arguments to *any* function, so the behavior probably comes from there.

ClojureScript might inherit its manners from JavaScript or from Clojure. [Clojure's documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote) explicitly states that `quote` with multiple arguments evaluates to the first of them only.

Common Lisp, another popular Lisp language, [also only accepts a single argument](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm) to `quote`:

```
$ sbcl
* (quote 1 2 3)
debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002B2AE83}>:
  wrong number of args to QUOTE:
 (QUOTE 1 2 3)
```

Note that in general, for any Lisp, `quote` is seldom spelled out. It is just a special form that is an expansion of `'`. In the `'` form, it is not even *possible* to give `quote` extra arguments:

```
'(1 2 3) ≡ (quote (1 2 3))
'x       ≡ (quote x)
'???     ≡ (quote 1 2 3)
```

I don't immediately see a problem with expanding `quote`'s definition in any given language to, in case of multiple arguments, evaluate them as a list, but I certainly do not see a use for that feature, either.

Answer (score 3):

The original idea of `QUOTE` is to denote a constant, especially for symbols and lists:

```
(quote sin)

(quote (sin 10))
```

To get the unquoted data we call `SECOND` or `CADR`.

```
(defun unquote (expression)
  (second expression))
```

For example we could call:

```
(unquote '(quote (sin 10)))
```

If we now allow the idea that `(quote sin 10)` is the same as `(quote (sin 10))`, then we would need to rewrite our unquote function for the two cases:

```
(defun unquote (expression)
  (if (consp (cddr expression))
    (cdr expression)
    (cadr expression)))
```

By adding that special case we would not get any new capabilities, but it would complicate code which has to deal with such expressions...

Answer (score 1):

In most lisps `quote` will error given more than one argument. This behaviour seems to be a peculiarity of Clojure (or ClojureScript?).

Allowing multiple arguments to `quote` to become a list isn't a very nice design. If you have an operation to make a list you should clearly be able to use it to construct a single element list, but modified `quote` does not allow that.

(I tested SBCL, Emacs Lisp and scheme48, all of which complain about quote with multiple arguments.)